# spring rabbit listen output queue or receive

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I am developing an application with rabbitmq support. So, I have a consumer and a producer. And I need to decide between two ways how to set up communication between both of them.

**The First Way**

```
public void send(){
   //send to consumer and forget
   rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("","routing-key",my object);
  //waiting for output queue and messages from consumer
  while(true){
     //receive something.
     if(corellationID==what we need){
        //do what we need
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

**The second way**

```
public void send(){
   //send to consumer and wait for result
   Object o=rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("","routing-key",my object);

}
```

Which way will work more quickly and stable under high loadings? And may be there another more effective way to do this. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second way as with the first way you will have to implement what the second way already does:

- create a correlation id
- maintain a map
- dequeue message from the reply queue
- correlate reply message with the producer
- ...

Btw the most effective way is to not have a thread that waits for the reply. and so works in an asynchronous way: the thread that sends the message may not be the one that receive the reply. [Have a look at the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e1073)

Comment: Thank you Nicolas! In other words, did you say that second method is the easiest way to achieve the result I need? Thank you

Comment: easiest way but not the more effective. It depends on your loads, see my edit

Comment: Thanks, but what the reason to start another thread? Anyway I will have to wait until it completes. I have JSON in and need to produce JSON out asap, I can wait for convertSendAndReceive and can wait for thread to complete, where the profit?

Comment: To be able to do something else with this thread while the reply is computed elsewhere. Asynchronous may not be easy to implement. You should balance with your requirement. You may start with a synchronous send and receive and refactor if needed